# How to install CPAN modules from the command line on OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, perl

Simple question: How to install CPAN modules on OS-X like normal Linux/Unix way?

I just want to type in `cpan` something like `install Perl6::Say` for example.

Answer (score 16):

Open the **/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app** and you have a unix prompt.

Both `perl` and `cpan` ship with OS X so you have nothing to install unless you want a different version of them than ships with your particular version and build of OS X.

```
Air:~ me$ cpan Perl6::Say
Sorry, we have to rerun the configuration dialog for CPAN.pm due to
some missing parameters...  Will write to
 <</Users/me/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm>>
```

Comment: Depending on the modules you want to install you may need to [install Xcode](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) as well so a compiler is available. Install Xcode before running `cpan` for the first time. If you've already configured `cpan` you may need to re-run it with `cpan config` so it picks up the compiler.

Comment: i'm trying, but always have status 'make or install: NO'. am i need to use `sudo`? but i want only for current user, not root all modules

Comment: Why not ask a follow on question. List exactly the module you want to install and exactly the error message you get. You may be missing the command line tools that Xcode can install or you may have another error. We like narrow, specific, answerable questions here. It's free to ask another question, so why not leave this as a signpost for how to get started and ask another on how to interpret a specific error message. I'll edit my answer to show that with Xcode and the command line tools installed, this works for a user install.

Comment: Please note that you don't need to add `install` on the command line for `cpan`. All you have to do is `cpan Perl6::Say`. If you include `install` it will try to install a module called `install`, which for this reason is an empty module, see https://metacpan.org/pod/install.

Comment: @simbabque I had no idea I was wrong there. Please feel you can edit my posts to fix this sort of thing and then leave an edit comment or a comment why you fixed it. I appreciate the correction!

Answer (score 9):

You might be interested in [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) to manage local perl installations and cpan modules without interfering with perl included with the system or needing to use `sudo` to install cpan modules.

Comment: This is a very nice solution for someone that cares not to install Xcode or other command line tools.